# How to get the sum of items selected in javascript with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have four groups of items which can be selected by clicking a radio button. Each group have a proper input name and one element can be selected in a group. I want to get the total sum of selected items.

```
<input id="montant_commande" type="text" name = "total" value = "0"/><br/>

<input type="radio" name = "Entree" />
<input type="radio" name = "Entree" />
<input type="radio" name = "Entree" />

<input type="radio" name = "Plats" />
<input type="radio" name = "Plats" />
<input type="radio" name = "Plats" />

<input type="radio" name = "Desserts" />
<input type="radio" name = "Desserts" />
<input type="radio" name = "Desserts" />

<input type="radio" name = "Boissons" />
<input type="radio" name = "Boissons" />
<input type="radio" name = "Boissons" />
```

Can you provide me a way to achieve that?

I've tried some javascript codes that do this:
- adding the price (concatenate) on every click in a group instead of adding one price (one item can be selected in a group).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    let somme = 0;
    var montant_commande =  document.getElementById('montant_commande');

    var Entree = document.getElementsByName('Entree');
    var Plats = document.getElementsByName('Plats');
    var Desserts = document.getElementsByName('Desserts');
    var Boissons = document.getElementsByName('Boissons');

    for(var i = 0; i < Entree.length; i++){
        Entree[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            if(this.checked){
                updatePrix(2000);
            }
        });
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < Plats.length; i++){
        Plats[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            if(this.checked){
                updatePrix(5000);
            }
        });
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < Desserts.length; i++){
        Desserts[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            if(this.checked){
                    updatePrix(3000);
            }
        });
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < Boissons.length; i++){
        Boissons[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            if(this.checked){
                updatePrix(1000);
            }
        });
    }

    function updatePrix(total){
        somme += total;
        montant_commande.value = somme;
    }
}
</script>
```

I expect that : in a group, one element can be selected so no concatenation of the total sum while clicking others in the same group to select an item.

Comment: you can iterate all radio and sum up all checked one when one radio is changed

Comment: As this is written, the total price would keep going up and up whenever someone changes their mind about their initial selection -- you have no code to do subtraction when an item is deselected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the following snippet based on your provided code. Here is what I did:

1. Added a form element so as to loop over the radio inputs once
2. Added the price to the radio's `value` attribute to generalize the calculation
3. Changed the `updatePrix` function to calculate the total when any input is changed

```js
let myForm = document.myForm;
for (var i = 0; i < myForm.length; i++) {
  if (myForm[i].type === 'radio') {
    myForm[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      updatePrix();
    });
  }
}

function updatePrix() {
  let somme = 0;
  let montant_commande =
    document.getElementById('montant_commande');

  for (var i = 0; i < myForm.length; i++) {
    if (myForm[i].type === 'radio' && myForm[i].checked) {
      somme += parseInt(myForm[i].value, 10);
      montant_commande.value = somme;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <input id="montant_commande" type="text" name="total" value="0" /><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="Entree" value="2000" />Entree 1<br />
  <input type="radio" name="Entree" value="2000" />Entree 2<br />
  <input type="radio" name="Entree" value="2000" />Entree 3<br />
  <input type="radio" name="Plats" value="5000" />Plats 1<br />
  <input type="radio" name="Plats" value="5000" />Plats 2<br />
  <input type="radio" name="Plats" value="5000" />Plats 3<br />
  <input type="radio" name="Desserts" value="3000" />Desserts 1<br />
  <input type="radio" name="Desserts" value="3000" />Desserts 2<br />
  <input type="radio" name="Desserts" value="3000" />Desserts 3<br />
  <input type="radio" name="Boissons" value="1000" />Boissons 1<br />
  <input type="radio" name="Boissons" value="1000" />Boissons 2<br />
  <input type="radio" name="Boissons" value="1000" />Boissons 3<br />
</form>
```